# Как запустить приложение AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular2, angular5

Только начал изучать `Angular`, есть готовый проект который хочу разобрать, но не могу его запустить, подскажите в чём проблема, буду очень благодарный.

Когда выполняю команду ng serve вылетает вот такая ошибка:

```
The Angular CLI configuration format has been changed, and your existing configuration can
be updated automatically by running the following command:

ng update @angular/cli
```

Когда выполняю эту команду что указана, ничего не происходит.

Когда выполняю команду ng update выдаёт вот такое:

```
   We analyzed your package.json, there are some packages to update:

  Name                               Version                  Command to update
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @angular/cli                       1.0.0-beta.30 -> 6.0.8   ng update @angular/cli
  @angular/core                      2.4.10 -> 6.0.4          ng update @angular/core
  rxjs                               5.5.11 -> 6.2.0          ng update rxjs


There might be additional packages that are outdated.
Or run ng update --all to try to update all at the same time.
```

Файл **package.json**

```
{
 "name": "angular-devise-token-seed",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "license": "MIT",
 "angular-cli": {},
 "scripts": {
 "ng": "ng",
 "start": "ng serve",
 "test": "ng test",
 "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
 "e2e": "protractor"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
"@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
"@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
"@angular/forms": "^2.4.10",
"@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
"@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
"angular2-materialize": "^6.7.0",
"angular2-token": "^0.2.0-beta.8",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"jquery": "^2.2.4",
"materialize-css": "^0.98.0",
"rxjs": "^5.0.1",
"ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
"zone.js": "^0.7.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.30",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
"@types/node": "^6.0.42",
"codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
"jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
"karma": "1.2.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
"protractor": "~4.0.13",
"raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
"ts-node": "1.2.1",
"tslint": "^4.3.0",
"typescript": "~2.0.3"
}
}
```

Comment: Готовый проект в студию.

Comment: Извиняюсь сразу за то что даю ссылку на гитхаб, по другому никак.
https://github.com/andrea2010/b

Comment: Вам говорят, что надо обновится. Поскольку вы обновили `@angular/cli`, то надо обновить и зависящие пакеты. Запустите команду `ng update --all` - она обновит все пакеты)